# Help required with assembly of Sain Smart 7 inch touch screen monitor kit and connection to pi

Tags: touchscreen

I am new to the pi and purchased the above kit which consists of several boards but no instructions regarding assembly.  There appears to be software instructions but being new I am in the dark!

I am familiar with windows and a PC.

Paul

Comment: A link to the kit and any instructions would help, also, have you tried Sain Smart support?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a direct link to the item but it is easily visible and findable on Sain Smart's web site. I've contacted their customer service who have merely pointed me to their item on the web site and "Download the manual" which only consists of software related matters.

Comment: You can simply copy/paste the address from the address bar. That *should* suffice.

Comment: The web address I have discovered is <http://www.sainsmart.com/7-inch-tft-lcd-monitor-for-raspberry-pi-touch-screen-driver-board-hdmi-vga-2av.html>

Comment: More Views

7 Inch TFT Touch Screen LCD Monitor For Raspberry Pi + Driver Board HDMI VGA 2AV
SKU:20-011-208
$73.99
Package list:
1x HDMI+VGA+2AV Controller Board VS-TY2662-V1 (Support Automatically switch to AV2 )
1x 7 inch 800* 480  Lcd Panel AT070TN92 with Touch Screen 
1x USB Controller Card 
1x USB Cable 
1x Remote Control ( not including the CR2025 3V Lithium cell )
1x CD including the driver for Touch Panel controller Card
Email to a Friend
Be the first to review this product
Sign up for price alert
Qty:
Add to Cart
-OR-

OR
Add to Wishlist
Add to Compare

Comment: is there any other place to download that custom kernel.img? The author seems to have left, and the google code archive keeps giving me errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find a power supply with a 5.5mm plug. I found a 5v 2.5a adapter from my dlink router. You only need 5v 1a to power the display. Just plug that into the lcd driver board (board with hdmi port on it). Next you need to connect the lcd to the driver board. Find the ttl port (it says TTL OUT in front of it) and push out the two grey hinge things. Connect the lcd ttl cable (big one) into the driver board and then push the grey hinge things in. Finally connect the RPI to the screen via HDMI or composite. I am working on getting the drivers for the touchscreen installed and I will get back when I figure that out.

EDIT: Drivers.
I finally found a website which tells you how to install the drivers. You have to build a new kernel with the touchscreen driver installed. I just downloaded the prebuilt kernel the person made. To install I moved the `kernel.img` to `/boot/`. I put the `modules` and `firmware` folders in `/lib/` folder. You have to be root to copy and move the files.

Website: http://engineering-diy.blogspot.ca/2013/01/adding-7inch-display-with-touchscreen.html

`files.tar.gz`: https://code.google.com/p/andrei-development/downloads/detail?name=kernel_3_6_11_eGalax_feb_2013.tar.gz

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Since my original question and some discussion with Sain Smart they have produced an instructional video but unfortunately I cannot get any sound and where they focus on the screen to demonstrate items it is out of focus! They are aware of the issue and are looking into it. Also they are using a 12 volt power supply and the output on the edge of the board for the screen on the model I have. The ribbon cable has also torn and I am awaiting a response from them about that as well. Watch this space!!

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/SainSmart-7-Raspberry-Pi-LCD-Display-Touch-Screen-TFT-Monitor-AT070TN90-with-HDMI-VGA-Input-Driver/1692644167.html) the unit requires 2A.

Comment: I've tried current from 1A to 3A, it all works. 2A is just suggested

Comment: Mine finally arrived and I was able to power it from a USB port on my desktop. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how much current it is drawing.